# Giuseppe Peano and Foundations: Was Peano Logicist or Formalist?

Tags: philosophy-of-mathematics, history-of-philosophy

I am trying to figure out whether the mathematician Giuseppe Peano (1858-1932), most notably known for his standard axiomatization of the natural numbers, held a view of Logicism or rather of Formalism. But I nevertheless get confused and hence my question: Was Peano's view closer to Russell's logicism or was it closer to Hilbert's formalism? What was Peano's view regarding foundations?

Comment: Neither: he did not express relevant "philosophical" views about *foundations*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can see [Arithmetices principia: nova methodo exposita](https://archive.org/details/arithmeticespri00peangoog) (1889), translated into:

- Jean van Heijenoort (editor), [From Frege to Gödel: A Source Book in Mathematical Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=v4tBTBlU05sC&pg=PA85) (1967), page 85-on:

> Questions that pertain to the foundations of mathematics, although treated by 
>   many in recent times, still lack a satisfactory solution. The difficulty has its main source in the ambiguity of language. [...] My goal has been to undertake this examination, and in this paper I am presenting the results of my study, as well as some applications to arithmetic.
>
> I have denoted by signs all ideas that occur in the principles of arithmetic, so that every proposition is stated only by means of these signs.
>
> The signs belong either to logic or to arithmetic proper. The signs of logic that occur here are ten in number, although not all are necessary.

Thus, it seems that *logic* and *arithmetic* - contrary to the founding fathers of *logicism*: Frege and Russell - are distinct.

But the signs **K** for *classes* and **∈** [*est*] for *membership* are listed as *logical signs*, and thus the theory of classes is part of logic, and this is common to Frege and Russell.

---

For a detailed discussion, see:

- Hubert C. Kenendy, [The Mathematical Philosophy of Giuseppe Peano](http://www.jstor.org/stable/186238?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) (1963),

where it is argued for a "rejection of the logicist thesis of the reduction of mathematics to logic." [Also available [here](http://hubertkennedy.angelfire.com/TwelveArticles.pdf)].